# Auto generating SilverStripe admin links

Tags: admin, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

So I have a DataObject that I manage via Model Admin via the standard gridfield (using Silverstripe 4)

I would like to be able to generate a link to edit this object directly the admin. I can do this if I manually enter the ModelAdmin URL, but this doesn't seem very dynamic (if we change admin URL's in the future then that approach will break).

I have tried to implement the below:

```
class MyObject extends DataObject
{
    public function EditLink()
    {
        $classname = str_replace('\\', '-', $this->owner->ClassName);
        $admin = OrderAdmin::singleton();
        $fields = $admin->getEditForm()->Fields();
        $grid = $fields
            ->fieldByName($classsname);

        return Controller::join_links(
            $grid->Link("item"),
            $this->owner->ID,
            "edit"
        );
    }
}
```

But this outputs this error & stacktrace:

```
[Emergency] Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: SilverStripe\ORM\DataObject is not a subclass of DataObject

POST /as-plumbing-app-v2/admin/jobs/Job/EditForm/field/Job/item/1/ItemEditForm/

Line 147 in /home/morven/Projects/as-plumbing-app-v2/vendor/silverstripe/framework/src/ORM/DataObjectSchema.php

Source

138     {
139         $class = ClassInfo::class_name($class);
140         $current = $class;
141         while ($next = get_parent_class($current)) {
142             if ($next === DataObject::class) {
143                 return $current;
144             }
145             $current = $next;
146         }
147         throw new InvalidArgumentException("$class is not a subclass of DataObject");
148     }
149 
150     /**
151      * Get the base table
152      *
153      * @param string|object $class
Trace

SilverStripe\ORM\DataObjectSchema->baseDataClass(SilverStripe\ORM\DataObject) 
DataQuery.php:165
SilverStripe\ORM\DataQuery->initialiseQuery() 
DataQuery.php:76
SilverStripe\ORM\DataQuery->__construct(SilverStripe\ORM\DataObject) 
DataList.php:61
SilverStripe\ORM\DataList->__construct(SilverStripe\ORM\DataObject) 
ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array) 
InjectionCreator.php:23
SilverStripe\Core\Injector\InjectionCreator->create(SilverStripe\ORM\DataList, Array) 
Injector.php:585
SilverStripe\Core\Injector\Injector->instantiate(Array, SilverStripe\ORM\DataList, prototype) 
Injector.php:988
SilverStripe\Core\Injector\Injector->getNamedService(SilverStripe\ORM\DataList, , Array) 
Injector.php:941
SilverStripe\Core\Injector\Injector->get(SilverStripe\ORM\DataList, , Array) 
Injector.php:1111
SilverStripe\Core\Injector\Injector->createWithArgs(SilverStripe\ORM\DataList, Array) 
Injectable.php:30
SilverStripe\View\ViewableData::create(SilverStripe\ORM\DataObject) 
SearchContext.php:160
SilverStripe\ORM\Search\SearchContext->getQuery(Array, , ) 
SearchContext.php:210
SilverStripe\ORM\Search\SearchContext->getResults(Array) 
ModelAdmin.php:347
SilverStripe\Admin\ModelAdmin->getList() 
OrderAdmin.php:166
SilverCommerce\OrdersAdmin\Admin\OrderAdmin->getList() 
ModelAdmin.php:184
SilverStripe\Admin\ModelAdmin->getEditForm(, ) 
OrderAdmin.php:88
SilverCommerce\OrdersAdmin\Admin\OrderAdmin->getEditForm() 
Estimate.php:151
SilverCommerce\OrdersAdmin\Model\Estimate->EditLink() 
JobDetailForm_ItemRequest.php:117
App\Forms\GridField\JobDetailForm_ItemRequest->doViewInvoice(Array, SilverStripe\Forms\Form, SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest, SilverStripe\Forms\FormRequestHandler) 
FormRequestHandler.php:231
SilverStripe\Forms\FormRequestHandler->httpSubmission(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest) 
RequestHandler.php:320
SilverStripe\Control\RequestHandler->handleAction(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest, httpSubmission) 
RequestHandler.php:201
SilverStripe\Control\RequestHandler->handleRequest(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest) 
RequestHandler.php:225
SilverStripe\Control\RequestHandler->handleRequest(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest) 
GridFieldDetailForm.php:118
SilverStripe\Forms\GridField\GridFieldDetailForm->handleItem(SilverStripe\Forms\GridField\GridField, SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest) 
GridField.php:1019
SilverStripe\Forms\GridField\GridField->handleRequest(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest) 
RequestHandler.php:225
SilverStripe\Control\RequestHandler->handleRequest(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest) 
RequestHandler.php:225
SilverStripe\Control\RequestHandler->handleRequest(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest) 
Controller.php:207
SilverStripe\Control\Controller->handleRequest(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest) 
LeftAndMain.php:750
SilverStripe\Admin\LeftAndMain->handleRequest(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest) 
AdminRootController.php:123
SilverStripe\Admin\AdminRootController->handleRequest(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest) 
Director.php:360
SilverStripe\Control\Director->SilverStripe\Control\{closure}(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest) 
VersionedHTTPMiddleware.php:40
SilverStripe\Versioned\VersionedHTTPMiddleware->process(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest, Closure) 
HTTPMiddlewareAware.php:62
SilverStripe\Control\Director->SilverStripe\Control\Middleware\{closure}(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest) 
AuthenticationMiddleware.php:61
SilverStripe\Security\AuthenticationMiddleware->process(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest, Closure) 
HTTPMiddlewareAware.php:62
SilverStripe\Control\Director->SilverStripe\Control\Middleware\{closure}(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest) 
CanonicalURLMiddleware.php:155
SilverStripe\Control\Middleware\CanonicalURLMiddleware->process(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest, Closure) 
HTTPMiddlewareAware.php:62
SilverStripe\Control\Director->SilverStripe\Control\Middleware\{closure}(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest) 
FlushMiddleware.php:26
SilverStripe\Control\Middleware\FlushMiddleware->process(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest, Closure) 
HTTPMiddlewareAware.php:62
SilverStripe\Control\Director->SilverStripe\Control\Middleware\{closure}(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest) 
RequestProcessor.php:66
SilverStripe\Control\RequestProcessor->process(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest, Closure) 
HTTPMiddlewareAware.php:62
SilverStripe\Control\Director->SilverStripe\Control\Middleware\{closure}(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest) 
SessionMiddleware.php:20
SilverStripe\Control\Middleware\SessionMiddleware->process(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest, Closure) 
HTTPMiddlewareAware.php:62
SilverStripe\Control\Director->SilverStripe\Control\Middleware\{closure}(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest) 
AllowedHostsMiddleware.php:60
SilverStripe\Control\Middleware\AllowedHostsMiddleware->process(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest, Closure) 
HTTPMiddlewareAware.php:62
SilverStripe\Control\Director->SilverStripe\Control\Middleware\{closure}(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest) 
TrustedProxyMiddleware.php:176
SilverStripe\Control\Middleware\TrustedProxyMiddleware->process(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest, Closure) 
HTTPMiddlewareAware.php:62
SilverStripe\Control\Director->SilverStripe\Control\Middleware\{closure}(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest) 
HTTPMiddlewareAware.php:65
SilverStripe\Control\Director->callMiddleware(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest, Closure) 
Director.php:369
SilverStripe\Control\Director->handleRequest(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest) 
HTTPApplication.php:48
SilverStripe\Control\HTTPApplication->SilverStripe\Control\{closure}(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest) 
call_user_func(Closure, SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest) 
HTTPApplication.php:66
SilverStripe\Control\HTTPApplication->SilverStripe\Control\{closure}(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest) 
call_user_func(Closure, SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest) 
ErrorControlChainMiddleware.php:56
SilverStripe\Core\Startup\ErrorControlChainMiddleware->SilverStripe\Core\Startup\{closure}(SilverStripe\Core\Startup\ErrorControlChain) 
call_user_func(Closure, SilverStripe\Core\Startup\ErrorControlChain) 
ErrorControlChain.php:236
SilverStripe\Core\Startup\ErrorControlChain->step() 
ErrorControlChain.php:226
SilverStripe\Core\Startup\ErrorControlChain->execute() 
ErrorControlChainMiddleware.php:69
SilverStripe\Core\Startup\ErrorControlChainMiddleware->process(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest, Closure) 
HTTPMiddlewareAware.php:62
SilverStripe\Control\HTTPApplication->SilverStripe\Control\Middleware\{closure}(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest) 
HTTPMiddlewareAware.php:65
SilverStripe\Control\HTTPApplication->callMiddleware(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest, Closure) 
HTTPApplication.php:67
SilverStripe\Control\HTTPApplication->execute(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest, Closure, ) 
HTTPApplication.php:49
SilverStripe\Control\HTTPApplication->handle(SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest) 
index.php:17
```

I am assuming that this is because I have not passed the correct response object to ModelAdmin when I created it, so it is unsure what ModelClass to use?

Does anyone have any ideas on the preferred way to implement this?

Answer (score 3):

This should work for SilverStripe 3 and 4 (Tested on 3.6 and 4.0)

```
class MyObject extends DataObject
{
    public function EditLink()
    {
        $classname = str_replace('\\', '-', singleton($this->owner->ClassName)->i18n_plural_name());
        $admin = OrderAdmin::singleton();
        $fields = $admin->getEditForm()->Fields();
        $grid = $fields->dataFieldByName($classname);

        return Controller::join_links(
            $grid->Link("item"),
            $this->owner->ID,
            "edit"
        );
    }
}
```

Changes made to your original include

- Using plural version of ClassName
- Fixing typo of `$classname` when requesting Grid
- using `->dataFieldByName()` rather than `->fieldByName()`

NOTE: SilverStripe 4.0 uses proper namespacing, so you also want to ensure you are using the correct namespace for DataObject.

E.g.

```
namespace MySite;

use SilverStripe\ORM\DataObject;

class MyObject extends DataObject
{
...
```

Comment: Hi Brent, thanks for the code, unfortunately this generates the same error :-s.

I am trying to add the link to the following (if that helps): https://github.com/silvercommerce/orders-admin/blob/1.0/src/model/Estimate.php

Comment: Sorry, I just realised I typed Brent instead of Brett, really sorry for the typo!

Comment: @PsychoMo I think the issue is related to your overloading of the `getList` function in your OrderAdmin class [https://github.com/silvercommerce/orders-admin/blob/1.0/src/admin/OrderAdmin.php#L166](https://github.com/silvercommerce/orders-admin/blob/1.0/src/admin/OrderAdmin.php#L166)

Rather than overloading the class you could use the extension instead to apply your additional filter?

Comment: I will give it a try and see if the getList function is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For SilverStripe 5, there is a new `CMSEditLinkExtension` to cover this use case. It also handles linking via related objects.

https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/5/developer_guides/model/managing_records/#getting-an-edit-link/

```php
// app/src/Model/MyModel.php
namespace App\Model;

use SilverStripe\Admin\CMSEditLinkExtension;
use SilverStripe\ORM\DataObject;

class MyModel extends DataObject
{
    private static string $cms_edit_owner = 'Parent';

    private static $has_one = [
        'Parent' => MyParentModel::class,
    ];

    private static $extensions = [
        CMSEditLinkExtension::class,
    ];
}
```

```php
// app/src/Model/MyParentModel.php
namespace App\Model;

use App\Admin\MyModelAdmin;
use SilverStripe\Admin\CMSEditLinkExtension;
use SilverStripe\ORM\DataObject;

class MyParentModel extends DataObject
{
    private static string $cms_edit_owner = MyModelAdmin::class;

    private static $has_many = [
        'Children' => MyModel::class,
    ];

    private static $extensions = [
        CMSEditLinkExtension::class,
    ];
}
```

Then you can simply use `CMSEditLink()` on any `MyModel` or `MyParentModel`.